# Why doesn't this Scheme sum-of-squares function work?

Tags: scheme

```
(define (square x)
  (display (* x x)))

(define (sum-of-squares a b) 
  (+ (square a) (square b)))
```

I tested it, and the `sum-of-squares` function does not work. Why?

Answer (score 9):

`(display x)` evaluates to void (could be seen as nothing). It is a function call that prints out the argument but doesn't return it. Instead you should define the square function to evaluate the value without displaying, that is:

```
(define (square x)
  (* x x))
```